# Remove all issues from Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console

I have a lot of issues in the google webmaster tools (like 25 000) that are in the past and have been solved.

I would like to remove all the issues to concentrate on the new ones, but I can only delete 1 000 of them per day.

How can I remove all the issue in one time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll just have to wait. If your website is crawlable and has a proper sitemap, Google will recrawl those pages, see that they're fixed and remove them from your Webmaster tools.

Yes, it's kinda annoying, but they're giving you a heads up to something you might otherwise not notice, which is pretty cool.

Just fix all the errors and they will disappear. I've had to do this for a website with a couple thousand errors (at launch). I just checked back every week to see what has changed. It can take a bit, but once they have figured out you are fixing it, the crawl rate will increase a bit and it will go (barely noticeable) faster :) You're not the only website with problems, you'll have to wait your turn.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You'll just have to settle with deleting 1,000 per day.